# rails instead link_to - render it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have controller for home, about, contact
I created navigation for that

```
<li><%= link_to 'Home' , homepage_path %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'About' , about_path %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'Contact' , contact_path %></li>
```

And it's working well, But now I created a navigation for my admin panel and I wanted to make it more organized so I did it with partials:
(on my /views/admin/index.html.erb )

```
<ul class="admin-nav">
    <li rel="posts">Posts</li>
    <li rel="pages">Pages</li>  
</ul>

<div class="posts panel">
    <%= render "posts/index" %>
</div>

<div class="pages panel">
    <%= render "pages/index" %>
</div>
```

But now let's say I'm clicking on the posts button on my admin panel, It no longer need to go to the posts_path, it needs to render it, Can I do that?

Comment: What are you are trying to accomplish? If you are just trying to do things the Rails way, you wouldn't render posts and pages partial pages in a single view. Those would be separate controllers/actions/views/etc. determined by the requested URL.

Comment: I have separate controllers, I just want to create a navigation to their views

Comment: Have you read this? https://www.railstutorial.org/book

Comment: It is a very good explanation of the the Rails way and you can read it all for free online.

Comment: Also, what your asking for is really not a Rails feature. You are asking for AJAX loading or a single page application created in JavaScript. http://emberjs.com/

Comment: I did it with Javascript, but I'm still not sure that this is the best way to do it, maybe i'm wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105319/discussion-between-user4571629-and-sacwebdeveloper).